# Amazon EC2 client builder without region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to a client's AWS using the secret key, access key, and role-arn in a java application.
Using AmazonEC2ClientBuilder requires the region to be specified.

Is there any way or any API support where I can connect to a client's AWS without the need for the region ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Amazon EC2 Java API (V2), you specify a region to tell the code which region your EC2 instances are you located in.

That is, if I have my EC2 instances in **USA West 2**, then I need to specify this region when creating a Service Client, as shown in this Java V2 code example that finds running Amazon EC2 instances in **USA West 2**.  You code still works without a region, but will default to a region. The default region for an SDK is **US-EAST-1**

```
package com.example.ec2;

// snippet-start:[ec2.java2.running_instances.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.Ec2Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.Filter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstancesRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstancesResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.Reservation;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.Instance;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.Ec2Exception;
// snippet-end:[ec2.java2.running_instances.import]

/**
 * To run this Java V2 code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class FindRunningInstances {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        Ec2Client ec2 = Ec2Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        findRunningEC2Instances(ec2);
        ec2.close();
    }

   // snippet-start:[ec2.java2.running_instances.main]
   // This method creates a Filter to find all running instances
   public static void findRunningEC2Instances(Ec2Client ec2) {

       try {
           String nextToken = null;

           do {
                Filter filter = Filter.builder()
                    .name("instance-state-name")
                    .values("running")
                    .build();

                DescribeInstancesRequest request = DescribeInstancesRequest.builder()
                    .filters(filter)
                    .build();

                DescribeInstancesResponse response = ec2.describeInstances(request);

                for (Reservation reservation : response.reservations()) {
                    for (Instance instance : reservation.instances()) {
                    System.out.printf(
                            "Found Reservation with id %s, " +
                                    "AMI %s, " +
                                    "type %s, " +
                                    "state %s " +
                                    "and monitoring state %s",
                            instance.instanceId(),
                            instance.imageId(),
                            instance.instanceType(),
                            instance.state().name(),
                            instance.monitoring().state());
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
            nextToken = response.nextToken();

            } while (nextToken != null);

        } catch (Ec2Exception e) {
           System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
           System.exit(1);
        }
      }
    // snippet-end:[ec2.java2.running_instances.main]
}
```